# Dialog icon missing in 2.3

Tags: android

I've been testing my app on an emulator running 2.2 and the ic_dialog_generic icon on the context menus and alert dialogs appear but when I switch to 2.3, they don't show up. The ic_dialog_info and ic_dialog_alert icons do though.

How do I handle this so that they show up on all versions? I'm using android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_xxxx to access them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try copying the icons from yoursdk/platforms/android-x/data/res/drawable to the res file in your app.

Comment: But is that the best way to handle it? I'm sure there are some minor changes, I'd rather not display 2.3 icons on 2.1 and mess with the ui.

Comment: @Roger See commonsware http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2224796/is-this-a-built-in-drawable