# Icon not showing up in 2.3.3?

Tags: android

In 2.2 there is a generic dialog icon (ic_dialog_generic). I used this in my program by accessing android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_generic. It shows up in 2.2, however when I tested it on 2.3.3, nothing showed up.

So I copied the drawable to my project and accessed it by R.drawable.ic_dialog_generic. Once again, it shows up in 2.2 but it still does not show up in 2.3.3.

It seems there was a change with context menu styles? Any idea?

Answer (score 2):

Duplicate question of [Dialog icon missing in 2.3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5630405/dialog-icon-missing-in-2-3)

Looking at the 2.3.3 source, this icon is definitely not there.  This illustrates why they keep warning us to copy the built in images to our own projects.

Comment: As I said in this question, I copied the drawable to my project and it still doesn't show up in 2.3.3.

Comment: If you copied it to your project, are you referencing the correct R class? If you're still referencing the Android one, it still won't find it. You need your packagename.R.drawable.ic_dialog_generic.

Comment: I'm doing .setIcon(R.drawable.ic_menu_add). As opposed to android.R.drawable.ic_menu_add.